# How to send headers with phpunit api request?

Tags: php, testing, http-headers, phpunit

I am trying to test my web service which is written in laravel 5 using phpunit. I am new to this testing framework. The application uses JWT for authentication which is passed in headers in the requests.

My test look likes so:

```
$response = $this->call('POST', 'authenticate', [
    'username' => 'carparts',
    'email' => 'admin@admin.com',
    'password' => 'password'
]);

$token = 'Bearer ' . json_decode($response->getContent())->token;

$response = $this->call('POST', 'users', [
    "first_name"    => "Test",
    "last_name"     => "Test",
    "email"         => 'test@test.com',
    "password"      => "testing",
    "role"          => "1"
], [], [], [
    'Authorization' => $token
]);

dd($response->getContent());
```

The token is returned fine but when I try to use in the next request to create a new user, it fails saying the token could not parsed from the request. When I do `request()->headers` in a middleware to check, even that does not show the header. What am I doing wrong? How to pass headers in a request using PHPUnit?

Answer (score 4):

There's a function to translate headers to server vars. Try passing this instead:

```
$this->transformHeadersToServerVars([ 'Authorization' => $token ])
```

Answer (score 0):

`$server` argument is an array of server variables, not http headers.
Pass your token as `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION`:

```
$response = $this->call('POST', 'users', [
    "first_name"    => "Test",
    "last_name"     => "Test",
    "email"         => 'test@test.com',
    "password"      => "testing",
    "role"          => "1"
], [], [], [
    'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' => $token
]);
```

Comment: Still won't work. I even tried to `dd($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'])` in my route to see but it said undefined index. Any idea?

Comment: I tried with HTTP_Authorization and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

just a wild guess...

check your .htaccess, it must contain

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent a day digging this problem.

What really happens when you run tests: you run phpunit command and then every request doesn't really sends, it's just run in current instance. It means that calling `$this->call()` doesn't invoke http request.

Every test case (i.e. test method) calls setUp method which runs createApplication method. All methods required by the kernel for booting up an application run in method `setUp()` which calls exactly before your test case:

```php
// Middleware
...
// There is nothing related to testCase 

function testCase() {
   // set header
}
// Action
...
// You can use header here
```

To solve this problem I add method exact before my test case. I still can't change headers but I don't really care. To get custom information I do the following:

```php
// in tests:
function _setHeader() {
  global $_TESTING_X_HEADER;
  $_TESTING_X_HEADER = "some-value";
}
function testCase() {
  // setUp will run with $_TESTING_X_HEADER == "some-value"
  // test goes here
}

// in middleware:
if(App::environment('testing')) {
  $h = global $_TESTING_X_HEADER;
} else {
  $h = request()->header('x-header');
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm using PHP unit to do some functional tests.

```
$client->request('GET','url', [], [], ['HTTP_Authorization' => $token]);
```

It works for me !